# How should I understand the extends keyword in typeScript? Examples inside

Tags: typescript

why type c inferred the **ture** ? I think it is wrong.
But how does it work？ Why got a different result from the **Equal**?

```
type s1<X> = <T>() => T extends X ? 1 : '2'
type k1 = s1<'s1'> //type k1 = <T>() => T extends "s1" ? 1 : "2"
type k2 = s1<'s2'> //type k2 = <T>() => T extends "s2" ? 1 : "2"
type c = k1 extends k2 ? true : false // type c = true


 type Equal<X, Y> =
  (<T>() => T extends X ? 1 : 2) extends
  (<T>() => T extends Y ? 1 : 2) ? true : false

type d = Equal<'s1', 's2'> // false
```

Comment: I'd say this is the same TypeScript bug as https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31006 and it's due to reusing the type `S1<X>` (please use UpperPascalCase for types, so `S1<X>`, `K1`, `K2`, `C`, `D`, etc).  There's not much to be done here other than to see if the proposed fix ever makes it into the language.  Does this answer your question? If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

`extends` tests if the left operand is a more specific subset of the right operand.

For example, `"foo" | "bar" extends string` is true, because `"foo" | "bar"` is more specific than `string`. It's a *subset* of the type `string`.

Likewise, `string extends "foo" | "bar"` is false.

It's easy to think about like this (pretend this is valid):

```
const variable: string = "foo" | "bar";
```

This is valid; "foo" or "bar" can be assigned to `string`.

However, this isn't:

```
const variable: "foo" | "bar" = string;
```

The string could be any string other than "foo" or "bar"!

Now I think where you're confused is that in this type:

```
type s1<X> = <T>() => T extends X ? 1 : '2'
```

It isn't:

```
type s1<X> = (<T>() => T) extends X ? 1 : '2'
```

But rather:

```
type s1<X> = <T>() => (T extends X ? 1 : '2')
```

You're passing strings to `s1`, so the resulting types are `() => (T extends 's1' ? 1 : "2").

I believe TypeScript perceives them as the same because they both have the same signature: `<T>() => string | number`.

This gives you `true`, the expected outcome.

Comment: `type s1<X> = <T>() => T extends X ? 1 : '2'` `type k1 = s1<'s1'> ` `const a: k1 = '2'`               If, as stated above，Type of a should be '2' but But not so . I'm still confused

Comment: Ah my bad. I mixed up precedence with the `<T>() => T extends ...`. If you wrap the function in parentheses you will find that it works: `(<T>() => T) extends ...`. I will update the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're talking about parenthesizing at all here; how does this address the question?  How does this account for the fact that `Equal` works differently?